# the correct inline-SVG markup structure for animation purposes?

Tags: javascript, svg, inline-svg

Let's say i want to animate the vector that looks like this with Javascript.

[Click Here .. ( Sorry my reputation Point bellow the requirement for image post)](https://ibb.co/d1vqQd)

then i divide it into 4 parts (head, body, 2 legs) and do some animation for each one of them..

What my question is, what is the correct markup structure for the vector above ??

from what I know .. there are 3 possibilities :

1. Group

   `<svg>
     <g id='head'>...</g>
     <g id='body'>...</g>
     <g id='leg_1'>...</g>
     <g id='leg_2'>...</g>
   </svg>`
2. Nested SVG

   `<svg>
     <svg id='head'>...</svg>
     <svg id='body'>...</svg>
     <svg id='leg_1'>...</svg>
     <svg id='leg_2'>...</svg>
   </svg>`
3. SVG for each part

   `<svg id='head'></svg>
   <svg id='body'></svg>
   <svg id='leg_1'></svg>
   <svg id='leg_2'></svg>`

I know there are many libraries that can help us in making an SVG animation, 
but that's not what I asked, what I want to know is how the markup structure should look ? 
So it can be easier for us to manipulate them

is there anyone who can give me a lil enlightenment about this ?

Comment: In theory any of these could work.

Answer (score 0):

Which of these structures you would use is not really determined by the fact that you want to animate them. The question you need to ask is, what is the most expressive way to formulate positioning, sizing and transformation properties for each of the parts, and for the relation to each other?

- If you use **groups in a parent svg**, coordinates are initially expressed relative to the viewport of the parent `<svg>` element.

  - with a SVG [`transform`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute) attribute or a CSS [`transform`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1) property on the `<g>` element, you can move the parts around inside the parent. (By "move" I mean any afine transformation, including rotating, scaling, flipping and skewing)
  - The coordinates the parts are expressed in would then be interpreted as sort of a "neutral" position within the parent.
- If you **nest svgs**, you establish new viewports for each part.

  - For each part you define a rectangle within which it is to be to rendered with attributes `x`, `y`, `width` and `height`. `preserveAspectRatio` resolves the positioning of the `viewBox` within. SVG or CSS `transform` can be used to move these rectangles around.
  - The coordinate system to express the child content in can be choosen with the `viewBox` attribute. Coordinates are then independent from any parent. Leaving the viewBox out, the result is equivalent to setting a `translate` transformation on a `<g>` element, using the respective `x` and `y` attribute values.
- If you use **separate svgs**, they are each positioned within the parent HTML following CSS rules.

  - Remember, positioning properties expressed as percentages [have different meaning in HTML and SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units). If you leave out the `viewBox` or the width/height properties on the `<svg>` element, there is a negotiation process to establish its size, and per HTML CSS rules, the sizes of parent elements may change.
  - The coordinate system of the child content is defined by the respective `viewBox` attributes.

A question more specific in your case is whether you want to use [CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-animations-1/) or [SMIL](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html) animations. While SMIL is not implemented by Microsoft browsers, it has the richer syntax fot timing and stacking multiple animations on the same property/attribute. It also has the capability to react to events, and you can animate the XML attributes. (Not all of them, but all the positioining attributes mentioned here.) CSS has the capability to define a `transform-origin` for each transformation, which in SVG is only implemented for `rotate` transforms.

So, if you want to animate the positioning of the parts within the parent, choosing CSS animation might determine the structure so as to avoid using XML attributes for that positioning.

Comment: I understand there is a challenge in maintaining the position on the SVG's element. especially for the `transform-origin` 
which are behave differently in each browser. 
but this already solved by the SVG libraries that are available at this time (e.g GSAP, svg.js , snap.svg)


And I'm not so sure of what you said about the coordinate system on point number 2 because they share the same coordinate system from the parent. CMIIW

Comment: The content _inside_ a nested svg element is expressed in its own coordinate system as soon as you set `viewBox`, see [Establishing a new viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#EstablishingANewViewport). For existing SVG-handling libraries, I am not aware of any that explicitely work with the distinction between SVG and CSS transform. They all seem to use SVG and compute the rest.

Comment: Sorry, I was too late for editing the previious comment. The first sentence must read: The content _inside_ a nested svg element is expressed in its own coordinate system that is translated by x and y, and additionally transformed as soon as you set `viewBox`, see [Establishing a new viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#EstablishingANewViewport).